# How to install Ubuntu from an external hard drive connected with a SATA to USB adapter cable?

Tags: system-installation, usb, mount, hard-drive, hardware

How would I write the install ISO to a hard drive which is [mounted](https://askubuntu.com/q/1333074/847449) through a USB adapter cable?

This can just be treated as a large USB "thumb" type drive?  It shows as:

```
/media/nicholas/3e798148-4333-4add-ba6c-f4272c17263e
```

or are additional steps needed to use it as a drive to install from?

Comment: How do you plan to make this drive able to boot so you can install from it?

Comment: I'm installing k3b, but would prefer unetbootin I think.  something like that?  I'm not sure @David

Comment: I do not know that app K3B but when I look it up I do not see how it installs a boot loader.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question becauset he OP has re asked the question later [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333082/how-to-make-an-external-hard-drive-bootable-with-unetbootin)

Comment: here @24601 an answer of "use unetbootin" would probably be sufficient.  The other q is how to use unetbootin.  My two cents.

Comment: @Nicholas Saunders You have asked four similar questions today, (so far). Each question is unique and well researched and written. If you tried to combine them someone would whine about more than one question per post and flag to close. Thank you for the opportunity to try and answer some good questions.

Answer (score -1):

### Installing Ubuntu FROM External USB Drive

Ubuntu can be installed **from** an external USB drive.

There are a few Challenges: Many Live installers such as Etcher, dd, mkusb, Gnome-Disks, Startup Disk Creator, Win32DiskImager, etc, clone the ISO as a ISO9660 partition and overwrite everything on the disk.

Other Live installers such as UNetbootin and YUMI-BIOS/UEFI, (version 0.0.8.1) will install to a partition on the disk, but only to a FAT32 partition They will not overwrite the whole disk like ISO9660 installers will. The maximum size of a FAT32 partition is 32GB on Windows, so most larger drives come as NTFS. A 4GB partition can be created on an external USB drive and Ubuntu Live can be installed to it.

YUMI-BIOS only, (version 2.0.7.9) and Universal USB installer, (version 1.9.9.7), will install to a NTFS partition without overwriting the whole disk or partition. These tools are available free from Pendrivelinux.com.

All of the above installers will overwrite any MBR on the partition being installed to, so we should be careful not to try to install Ubuntu or, any Linux, to a partition with a useful OS on it.