# How to make a virtual machine with .vdi file

Tags: virtualbox, vdi

Recently I lost everything on my PC and reinstalled Windows. But I have my old Ubuntu virtual machine's .vdi file.

Can I make a virtual machine with that .vdi file? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using VirtualBox, then it is not too difficult to take a VDI and use it anywhere. Here's how:

- copy your `.vdi` file to a directory where VirtualBox will be able to access it
- run VirtualBox and create a new virtual machine
- choose Ubuntu Linux as the operating system and click "Next"
- under the "Virtual Hard Disk" option, choose "Use existing hard disk". This will open the "Virtual Media Manager".
- in the Virtual Media Manager, click the "Add" button and select the `.vdi` file that you copied, then click "Next"
- configure the rest of the virtual machine as you would like it to be
- start the virtual machine

So long as the `.vdi` file has not been corrupted, it will work just fine.

Comment: Well written. +1

Comment: I got an error when adding .vdi file 'Could not get the storage format of the medium 'C:\Users\NO-NAME\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu.vdi' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).'

Comment: Can you delete the .vdi file after you create the VM?

Comment: @DanielW. the VDI file is used as the storage device, so deleting the file will delete all the data contained within.

Answer (score 4):

### Convert VDI File to Full Install

**You also have the option to convert a .vdi file to an .img file and flash that to HDD or USB.**

- Log into Ubuntu.
- Open VirtualBox
- cd to folder that contains ubuntu.vdi and run:

`VBoxManage clonemedium --format RAW ubuntu.vdi ubuntu.img`

This will create the Ubuntu image file

**Install Image File to target drive**

**Caution: The target drive will be overwritten**.

- Use Gnome-Disks, Etcher, Rufus, dd or mkusb when you want to restore or clone the image to another HDD or USB drive.

For using Etcher or Rufus to flash an image to HDD see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1333112/43926

Comment: with this can't I make a new virtual machine

Comment: @Aesha Amoli: This answer is to give you an option to be able to run your old virtual machine from a USB or from a HDD. matigo's answer is the one you asked for, mine is just an option.

Comment: ohk then i have to live boot it and get all deleted files, am i right? btw 'VBoxManage clonemedium --format RAW ubuntu.vdi ubuntu.img' isn't working on cmd

Comment: Are you running it from within the folder that has the .vdi file? "ubuntu.img" should be changed to the name of your image file