# How to Restore a virtualbox ubuntu 20.04 backup on Main Hard Disk

Tags: virtualbox, backup

I've searched a lot, but I didn't find the solution to this type of question!
I have an installed windows 10 on my Laptop and an installed ubuntu 20.04.01 on my Virtualbox. I want to know is it possible that I get a full backup from my ubuntu inside the Virtualbox and then delete my windows and after installing ubuntu 20.04 as my main OS, restore that back up over it and use ubuntu forever after that?

I would like to know if it is possible; how can I do that? And if it isn't, what is the reason?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: @user68186 tnx for the reply and for the explanation. This does make sense.

Comment: Should not be a problem, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1334277/43926. If working in Windows, cd to the folder where VBoxManage.exe is kept. Use `VBoxManage.exe clonehd --format RAW Ubuntu - 20.04.img 20.04.vdi` to convert `.vdi` to `.img` file. Give full path to source image. Use Rufus, Etcher, Win32DiskImager, etc to flash the `.img` file to disk.

Comment: If you want me to provide step by step instructions let me know.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron tnx for help. I understand the procedure, but I didn't understand this part "Give full path to source image". When should I do this and how? tnx in advance

Comment: Easiest way might be to put your source VDI file into C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\, (the folder VBoxManage.exe is located in). Then before running the command in Command Prompt, cd to that folder. The resulting IMG file may be larger than the VDI file.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I get that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let me know if this works for you and I will change my comment to an answer.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron ok. But this may take a while because I still have to do some stuff with my windows in the next few months and change some settings. After that, I'm going to do this procedure. I ask this now because I wanted to make sure that I don't do a lot with my ubuntu in a virtual box if it isn't possible.