ubuntu 24.04.10 LTS instalation issue (need help fast)
im trying to install ubuntu 22.04.10 LTS on a 16 GB usb drive, but everytime the installation stops at "aquiring and extracting image from cp:///tmp/tmp/tmplfqs_m6q/mount" ive left it for about 30-40 minutes and still at the same point.

Are you creating the live installer? or a full install to a 16GB flash drive? 16GB is not large for a full install of Ubuntu. And flash drives are slow, particularly in writes. Better to use a lightweight flavor for full install.

i have already created the life installer on it. but trying to fully install it on the flash drive. how much space would you recommend?

You need two USB, if you want to fully install Ubuntu on a USB. One USB for live install media. Second USB to install Ubuntu into. You can't do a full install onto the first USB used as installation media.

ive already setup the live install media on a spare usb and trying to install the whole thing on a 16 GB usb drive

Your 16 may work but Ubuntu now is larger. And with snaps even larger still. Have seen users with 20GB of snaps alone. I use 24.04 Kubuntu and totally uninstall all snaps. I am using 11 GB since newer install without all the things I accumulate by time of next LTS release. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333082/how-to-make-an-external-hard-drive-bootable-with-unetbootin  Really recommend a light weight flavor and settings to reduce writes as Flash really slow. I now prefer SSD for external drive installs. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours Lighter:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie

This question is similar to: How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
